# Error on EJB upgrade to JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm trying to upgrade the EJB module to work with JBoss AS 7 and after including all the libraries I thought might make a difference I'm sitll getting this error:

```
Error(20,33):  package org.jboss.ejb3.annotation does not exist
```

on:

```
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout;
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: If I import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.TransactionTimeout; I don't have a problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Maven?  If so, adding these dependencies to your POM may be helpful:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
   <artifactId>crc-jboss-client-all</artifactId>
   <type>pom</type>
   <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.jboss.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-jboss-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you were using JDeveloper; I had the same issue doing a build with Maven. The dependency comes from [jboss-annotations-ejb3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jboss/jboss-annotations-ejb3/4.2.2.GA).

Jon's answer didn't match the dependencies for `jboss-annotations-ejb3`. Therefore for Maven I added this to the `pom.xml`. May help some others.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-annotations-ejb3</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```